# microservice file upload/download central vs distributed api

Tags: microservices, security

In microservice architecture, let's say I have 4 services that will need file upload/download feature, I have two options for this:

1. I can create another new service(5th) to expose an file
   upload/download API.

But when it comes file download authorization, the download privilege actually depends on the other 4 services data (if the user can acces this customer, then he can download the customer's contract), this will introduce an high coupling with the other 4 services, and when the data types (customer order contract...) increase, it will become more complicated.

2. I can duplicate an file upload/download API on each of the 4
   services, since all the data is avalibel locally for each service,
   the cohesion will be very high.

Which one will you choose, or do you have any other solution?

Comment: The dedicated files service could generate "authorized download URL", at behest of other services. It is a URL with an expire-able special token parameter that files service can verify before starting the download.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you could move the authorisation to a claim which would be appended to the users token and sent with all service calls.

If you can't do that you could have the FileStorage microservice, but only expose ot to other services rather than the user directly. The Customer (or whatever) service can be injected with an interface for the FileStorage service, do its auth check and only get/return the file if it passes